# Postional arguments error when using scipy.optimize curve_fit command to estimate parameters of a system of ODEs

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to estimate parameters for numerically solving the classic Hare-Lynx predator-prey differential equations model. I've loaded my data into a dataframe, df, whose indices are the 91 years 1845-1935 and whose columns, df['Hare'] and df['Lynx'] record the animal populations. The system has six parameters, a,b,c,d,k,r.

I first tried solving the system using specified parameters, where `odeint` was imported from `scipy.optimize`:

```
def myode(x, t): # Code in the system of DEs: input is dependent, indep variable
  H = x[0] # redefine H as the 1st component of x
  L = x[1] # redefine L as the 2nd component of x
  r=1.6 #specify values of six parameters
  k=125
  d=.56
  c=50
  b=.6
  a=3.2
  dHdt=r*H*(1-H/k)-a*H*L/(c+H) # the system itself
  dLdt=a*b*H*L/(c+H)-d*L
  return [dHdt,dLdt]  # Return system of DEs

H0 = 19.58 #initial Hare population
L0 = 30.09 #initial Lynx population

t=np.arange(0,df.shape[0],1)
P0 = [H0,L0] 
Pop = odeint(myode, P0,t)   # Numerically solve the diff eqns
```

This works fine and produces a 91-by-2 array of population values.

Now, instead of specifying the parameter values, I try to estimate them using `curve_fit` from `scipy.optimize` along with my actual population data:

```
H0 = 19.58
L0 = 30.09
P0 = [H0,L0]

t_real=np.arange(0,df.shape[0],1)
H_real=df['Hare'].to_numpy()
L_real=df['Lynx'].to_numpy

def fitfunc(t,a,b,c,d,k,r):
  def myode(x, t):       
    H = x[0]           
    L = x[1]
    dHdt=r*H*(1-H/k)-a*H*L/(c+H)
    dLdt=a*b*H*L/(c+H)-d*L
    return [dHdt,dLdt]
  P = odeint(myode, P0, t)
  return P
params_guess=np.array([1,1,1,1,100,1])
param_fit, pcov = curve_fit(fitfunc, t_real,H_real,L_real,p0=params_guess)
```

The result is

TypeError: curve_fit() got multiple values for argument 'p0'

Comment: Show the full traceback.  I'm guessing `curvefit` is trying to call `fitfunc` with `t` and `a`, but it requires 5 added values.  I suggest rereading `cuvefit` docs.

Comment: `L_real=df['Lynx'].to_numpy` is just one function; missing `()`.  `p0` is supposed to be `Initial guess for the parameters (length N).  For this `fitfunc` you want to pass 6 scalars (or list/tuple/array) of the same length.

Comment: I see. So when I call curve_fit I need to specify initial parameter guesses, which would be. a 6-by-1 vector.

Comment: So, I've incorporated your suggested changes (see edits) but am still having problems.

Comment: The documentation suggests you should try passing in `p0=None`. If you want to refine that, pass in that 6-element vector and set a `breakpoint()`, then step through the library code to see what blew up. Show us the trace results. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Comment: Perhaps a question before I delve into setting a breakpoint. Looking at the documentation, ```scipy.optimize.curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata,p0=None)``` it says ```xdata``` is a k-by-M array containing the k predictors and ```ydata``` is a length M array. Is ```curve_fit``` really even the correct tool, since my dependent variable is 2-dimensional?